# Capybara: Link with HTML content not found

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, capybara

Given a HTML structure like this

```
<a href="…"><strong>My Link</strong></a>
```

is not caught by Capybara through a cucumber step

```
When I follow "My Link"
```

using a default webstep

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end
```

while this works:

```
When I follow "<strong>My Link</strong>"
```

I haven't been using Capbybara for long, but I can see what causes the problem. So, on a more general level — what's the proper way to go about this? Surely this case has to be pretty common, right?

Any ideas and general musings about Cucumber abuse very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move strong tag outside anchor tag or better use CSS for that.

Or you can assign id attribute to link and use it instead of content. This way is the best if your app supports multiple languages.

Otherwise you have to write some sort of xpath selector for such special case:

```
find(:xpath, "//a[contains(//text(), \"#{locator}\")]").click
```

Not tested, just an idea.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to keep the structure intact, since this is only a simplified example. Often styling requires one or multiple tags within a link, but the text content of the link isn't really affected. The idea of using an ID attribute might be more feasible, even though I'd not want to add anything to mark-up just for the test's sake. I'll check your selector suggestion.